# Бинарная сериализация и десериализация из разных сборок

Tags: c#, сериализация, binary

Имеется VB.Net программа, которая в данный момент портируется на C#. Настройки старой программы бинарно сериализируются в bin-файл и должны быть десериализованы новой. На этом этапе столкнулся с невозможностью десериализовать файл, созданный в старой программе, в новой. В самом начале выводилась ошибка о сборке. После переименования пространства имён на аналогичное старому ошибка пропала, но появилась новая [System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.serializationexception?view=netframework-4.6.2) при вызове метода [Deserialize](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.deserialize?view=netframework-4.6.2) у [BinaryFormatter](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=netframework-4.6.2):

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups()
    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler, System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser, bool, bool, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage)
    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(System.IO.Stream, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler, bool, bool, System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMethodCallMessage)
    System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(System.IO.Stream)
    Namespace.Serializer.Deserialize<T>(string, T) in Serializer.cs
    Namespace.Serializer.Deserialize<T>(string) in Serializer.cs
```

С помощью [yolosora](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/235621) был реализован свой SerializationBinder и теперь десериализация проходит, но содержит только объект верхнего уровня, а его свойство `List<Block> Items` ровно `null`.

#### Serializer класс

```cs
namespace Namespace
{
    public static class Serializer
    {
        public static bool TrySerialize<T>(string path, T instance, out Exception exception)
        {
            exception = null;
            try
            {
                Serialize(path, instance);
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                exception = ex;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static void Serialize<T>(string path, T instance)
        {
            using (Stream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            using (Stream gz = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                bf.Serialize(gz, instance);
            }
        }

        public static bool TryDeserialize<T>(string path, out T result, out Exception exception) where T : new()
        {
            return TryDeserialize(path, out result, new T(), out exception);
        }

        public static bool TryDeserialize<T>(string path, out T result, T defaultInstance, out Exception exception) where T : new()
        {
            exception = null;
            try
            {
                result = Deserialize(path, defaultInstance);
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                exception = ex;
                result = default;
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static T Deserialize<T>(string path, T defaultInstance)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
                return defaultInstance;
            }

            using (Stream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            using (Stream gz = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                bf.Binder = new IgnoreAssemblyBinder();

                // В следующей строке выбрасывалось исключение
                // System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
                return (T)bf.Deserialize(gz);
            }
        }

        public static T Deserialize<T>(string path) where T : new()
        {
            return Deserialize(path, new T());
        }
    }
}
```

Сериализируемые классы идентичны, т.е. имеют одинаковые имена типов и свойств. Типы свойств также идентичны.
Находил информацию, что как бы не были идентичны типы в разных сборках - они всё равно разные и это является причиной возникающей ошибки.

Имеется ли какой-либо способ выполнить бинарную десериализацию в другой сборке? Может поможет выделение кода сериализации и десериализации с типами в отдельную сборку?

---

#### Десериализируемые классы и объект

```cs
public class Blocks {
  public List<Block> Items { get; set; }
}
public class Block {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<BlockItem> Items { get; set; }
}
public class BlockItem {
  public Color ItemColor { get; set; }
  public OtherNs.FromOtherAssembly { get; set; }
  // остальные свойства имеют обычные типы
  // string, bool, int, double
}

// в WinForms -> Program.cs
public static blocks = Serializer.Deserialize<Blocks>("path/to/bin/file");
```

#### Реализация SerializationBinder

```cs
public class IgnoreAssemblyBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        Type type = null;
        if (typeName.StartsWith("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Namespace.BlockItem"))
        {
            type = typeof(List<BlockItem>);
        }
        else if (typeName.StartsWith("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Namespace.Block"))
        {
            type = typeof(List<Block>);
        }
        else if (typeName == "Namespace.Blocks")
        {
            type = typeof(Blocks);
        }
        else if (typeName == "Namespace.Block")
        {
            type = typeof(Block);
        }
        else if (typeName == "Namespace.BlockItem")
        {
            type = typeof(BlockItem);
        }
        else if (typeName == "System.Drawing.Color")
        {
            type = typeof(System.Drawing.Color);
        }
        else if (typeName == "OtherNs.FromOtherAssembly")
        {
            type = typeof(OtherNs.FromOtherAssembly);
        }
        else
        {
            type = Type.GetType($"{typeName}, {assemblyName}");
        }
        return type;
    }
}
```

Каждый вызов BindToType возвращает корректный тип из текущей сборки, но в десериализируемом объекте свойство Items всё равно равно null.

---

### Ссылки по теме

1. [SerializationBinder](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder?view=netframework-4.6.2)
2. [Класс BinaryFormatter](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=netframework-4.6.2)
3. [Свойство BinaryFormatter.Binder](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.binder?redirectedfrom=msdn&view=netframework-4.6.2)
4. [Метод BinaryFormatter.Deserialize](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.deserialize?view=netframework-4.6.2)

---

### Update

Проблема заключалась в отсутствии приватных полей в новом классе, т.е. в новых классах вместо явного указания приватных полей использовалась короткая нотация автосвойств:

```cs
public type PropName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Я в своем проекте тонну вариантов серриализаций за 5 лет перепробовал, но с вашим вариантом не пробовал, Но решая задачи и пытаясь и понять, недавно читал о тонкостях тут `Программирование на платформе Microsoft.NET Framework 4.5 на языке C#. 4-е издание` возможно поможет

Comment: И еще я применил одну хитрость, когда я в файлах конфигов хранил серриализованные json а потом их восстанавливал, я имел проблемы с изменениями в классах и не возможностью восстановить данные из старых конфигов. Так я применил хитрость, я json паковал base64 а потом уже серриализовал общий конфиг в бинари.

Comment: @Akina старая программа используется клиентами и необходимо реализовать совместимость файлов бинарной конфигурации. Сам охотно использую сериализацию в JSON, но это не тот случай, когда моё мнение что-то решает.

Comment: @Akina Ваши высказывания можно расценить как агрессивные... Я ничего не пытаюсь шифровать. Имеется старая программа на VB.Net, которая должна быть "один-в-один" портирована на C#. Естественно конфигурация должна быть прочитана новой программой. И "Да", нужна совместимость, а не совместное использование.

Comment: Ну нет - значит нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый вариант: (как оказалось не справляется с Generic-ами, скорее всего можно подшаманить)

```
class IgnoreAssemblyBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        var currentAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
        return Type.GetType($"{typeName}, {currentAssembly}");
    }
}
```

Метод тогда будет такой:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(string path, T defaultInstance)
{
    if (!File.Exists(path))
        return defaultInstance;

    using Stream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    using Stream gz = new GZipStream(fs, CompressionMode.Decompress);
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter
    {
        Binder = new IgnoreAssemblyBinder()
    };

    return (T)bf.Deserialize(gz);
}
```

Второй вариант:

```
static Assembly AssemblyResolver(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
}
```

Использование:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolver;
var parsedObj = Serializer.Deserialize(...);
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve -= AssemblyResolver;
```

Comment: Пробовал так: `bf.Binder = new IgnoreAssemblyBinder();` - исключение остаётся такое-же и в том-же месте.

Comment: @XelaNimed я на простом классе пробовал, возможно есть какие-то проблемные поля. Я бы попробовал BindToType метод поотлаживать, возможно меняется что-то лишнее и имеет смысл навернуть дополнительную логику на assemblyName/typeName

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Сейчас проблема с `System.Collections.Generic.List`1`.

Comment: @XelaNimed обновил ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо за уделяемое Вами время, но при десериализации объекта его свойство `public List<CustomType> { get; set; }` не десериализируется, т.е. равно `null`. Уже и не знаю что делать... В `BindToType` уже для каждого запроса отдаю конкретный тип с помощью `typeof`, но создаётся только самый верхний объект со свойством null.

Comment: @XelaNimed при варианте с `AssemblyResolve`'ом если что не нужен `SerializationBinder`

Comment: Только что попробовал с AssemblyResolver'ом - тот-же результат.

Comment: @XelaNimed тогда нужен MVCE :(

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103654/discussion-between-xelanimed-and-yolosora).